# Is there a way to automatically download output files in Kaggle Kernels or upload them to GoogleDrive?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, kaggle

I'm training a neural network using kaggle kernels, and save the model, the Tensorboard data and the keras history. It's always very tedious to download the output data one by one after tweaking each hyperparameter, is there a way to download the whole folder or to make a function, which uploads everything to a Google Drive?

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that all your data resides in a run/ folder in the Kaggle working directory, then you could zip the folder and download:

```
!pip install zip_files
!zip-folder --auto-root --outfile /kaggle/working/run.zip /kaggle/working/run
```